# Facing the StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer valid issue. please check if there is wayout

Tags: python-2.7

def ServerTimeWait(self):
        driver = GenericFunctionLibrary.get_webdriver_instance()
        try:
            ElemStatus = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//td/span[contains(text(),'server time:')]/following::span[2]")
            ))
            AppServerTime = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td/span[contains(text(),'server time:')]/following::span[2]").text
            if AppServerTime.endswith(' (UTC+2)'):
               UAppServerTime = AppServerTime[:-8]
            #print("AppServerTime :",AppServerTime)
            formatAppServerTime = datetime.strptime(UAppServerTime, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
            print ("formatAppServerTime:",formatAppServerTime)
            fmt = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
            now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
            #print ("now_utc.strftime(fmt):",now_utc.strftime(fmt))
            now_paris = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('Europe/Paris'))
            # #print "now_paris.strftime(fmt):",now_paris.strftime(fmt)
            # now_kolkata = now_paris.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
            # #print ("now_kolkata.strftime(fmt)",now_kolkata.strftime(fmt))
            finalSysDate = now_paris.strftime(fmt)
            print ("finalSysDate",finalSysDate)
            if formatAppServerTime == finalSysDate:
                print("Application server time is matched to current date")
            else:
                print("Application server time is not matched to current date")
        except Exception as e:
            raise e

Comment: Please show the code you used. Also, [have a look at how to ask questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Format the code using proper spacing and newlines. This one is not readable